# Command Prompt - outputting results without overwriting target file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I have a situation where I output results from a CLI program:

e.g. input.exe > output.txt

Although output.txt already contains text, by default it gets overwritten when using the command above, how can you write the output to output.txt without overwriting existing data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `>>` operator; it appends the output to the existing content of the file.

```
input.exe >> output.txt
```

Comment: No worries, more than happy to :)